# I need to print different dictionaries which have different fields, ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames:

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have 4 dictionaries and some of the fields are not present in all the 4. I get this error

> ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'from', 'Command'

After reading some docs I found  *extrasaction='ignore'* parameter for DictWriter but it leaves out some fields in the CSV file.
I need all the fields in the CSV file even though they are empty for some of the dictionaries. From what I understand it is just printing the common fields.

The dictionaries are:

> {'Command': 'DELETE', 'table': 'abc', 'from': 'abc', 'where_expr': 'c  =  book'}
>
> {'Command': 'SELECT', 'columns': 'a    b', 'table': 'tab1', 'from': 'tab1'}
>
> {'Command': 'INSERT', 'table': 'xyz', 'into': 'xyz', 'columns': 'pencil  pens', 'values': '200  20'}
>
> {'Command': 'UPDATE', 'table': 'Student', 'columns': 'NAME', 'values': 'PRATIK', 'where_expr': 'a  =  100'}

I have included extrasaction because of the error.

```
with open('del.csv', 'w') as f:  
    write = csv.DictWriter(f, dict4.keys(),extrasaction='ignore') 
    write.writeheader()
    write.writerow(dict5)
    write.writerow(dict6)
    write.writerow(dict7)
    write.writerow(dict8)
```

Output looks something like:
(I have used commas to separate the fields. Empty spaces mean empty fields(they have no value))

> table| columns|values| where_expr
>
> abc, , ,c  =  book
>
> tab1,a    b, , ,
>
> xyz,   pencil pens,200  20,
>
> Student    ,NAME,  PRATIK, a  =  100

Edited: The required output is:
(Empty spaces mean empty fields) I wish I could post the CSV file.

> Command|Table|Columns|From|Where_expr|Into|Values
>
> DELETE,abc, ,abc,c = book, , ,
>
> SELECT,tab1, a b,tab1, , , ,
>
> INSERT,xyz,pencil pens, , ,xyz, 200 20
>
> UPDATE, student,name, ,a = 100, , PRATIK

Comment: post the desired output

Comment: Posted it @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: could we have another order of fields?

Comment: Yes the order is not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [set.union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union) operation (for a case with dynamic number of columns):

```
import csv

dict5 = {'Command': 'DELETE', 'table': 'abc', 'from': 'abc', 'where_expr': 'c = book'}
dict6 = {'Command': 'SELECT', 'columns': 'a b', 'table': 'tab1', 'from': 'tab1'}
dict7 = {'Command': 'INSERT', 'table': 'xyz', 'into': 'xyz', 'columns': 'pencil pens', 'values': '200 20'}
dict8 = {'Command': 'UPDATE', 'table': 'Student', 'columns': 'NAME', 'values': 'PRATIK', 'where_expr': 'a = 100'}

with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    # `initial_fieldnames` are your dict4 keys
    initial_fieldnames = ["table", "columns", "values", "where_expr"]
    fieldnames = sorted(set(initial_fieldnames).union(*[dict5, dict6, dict7, dict8]))
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore')

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows([dict5, dict6, dict7, dict8])
```

---

`names.csv` contents:

```
Command,columns,from,into,table,values,where_expr
DELETE,,abc,,abc,,c = book
SELECT,a b,tab1,,tab1,,
INSERT,pencil pens,,xyz,xyz,200 20,
UPDATE,NAME,,,Student,PRATIK,a = 100
```

Comment: So all I had to do was manually give some field names and then perform union on the rest. Thanks!

Comment: @shaikhafizunnisa, No, not manually. `initial_fieldnames` is a pointer for your `dict4` keys. As you did not post `dict4`. Replace `initial_fieldnames` with your `dict4.keys()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas data frame to load all dictionaries in a list and make csv file from that dataframe. Try this :

```
import pandas as pd
d1 = {'Command': 'DELETE', 'table': 'abc', 'from': 'abc', 'where_expr': 'c = book'}
d2 = {'Command': 'SELECT', 'columns': 'a b', 'table': 'tab1', 'from': 'tab1'}
d3 = {'Command': 'INSERT', 'table': 'xyz', 'into': 'xyz', 'columns': 'pencil pens', 'values': '200 20'}
d4 = {'Command': 'UPDATE', 'table': 'Student', 'columns': 'NAME', 'values': 'PRATIK', 'where_expr': 'a = 100'}
d = [d1, d2, d3, d4]
d2 = []
col = ['Command', 'table', 'columns', 'from', 'where_expr', 'into', 'values']
for i in d:
    temp = {}
    for c in col:
        if c in i:
            temp[c] = i[c]
        else:
            temp[c] = ''
    d2.append(temp)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2, columns=col)
df2.columns = [c.capitalize() for c in col]
df2.to_csv('test21.csv', index=False, sep=',')
```

**Output** (csv file content) :

```
Command,Table,Columns,From,Where_expr,Into,Values
DELETE,abc,,abc,c = book,,
SELECT,tab1,a b,tab1,,,
INSERT,xyz,pencil pens,,,xyz,200 20
UPDATE,Student,NAME,,a = 100,,PRATIK
```

Comment: Exactly what I want! Can you explain me what is the second argument columns=col doing in DataFrame()?  And what is index=False. I just started learning Pandas,

Comment: @shaikhafizunnisa If you `print(df2)` there will be row names in the left most side, normally they are `0,1,2,3..`. To not write these row names, we set `index=False`. And the parameter `columns=col` says while making this dataframe, only use `col` list as the headers in the dataframe columns. Take a look at [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)